# Can't send email on ubuntu with mail command

Tags: ubuntu, email

on my ubuntu server (DigitalOcean droplet) I'm trying to send an email for first time.

I downloaded mailutils and mailx with following command:

```
sudo apt install mailutils -y
```

On configuration screen I chose default options: Internet site and then name sender as my droplet name.

To send email I do the following (replacing myemail@example.com):

```
echo "Hello world" | mail -s "Test" myemail@example.com
```

But nothing happens, I get no error message or anything, I checked my inbox and spam folders but nothing is there...

I also don't know where mail logs are placed on my system, I haven't found anything... Please help me.

I followed this turorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/send-email-linux-command-line

Comment: As your question is tagged with Ubuntu, the logs for mail are `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/messages`. Tail the logs when using the `mail` command and add their output to the question.

Comment: None of these log files exist on my server

Comment: `/var/log/syslog`. I don't know what release of Ubuntu you have but `/var/log/mail.log` exists on 22.04. Perhaps your system has `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-197-generic x86_64) @Nasir Riley

Comment: @gabogabans: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue.  Thanks in advance.